# Float point instructions on ARM assembly

Tags: c, performance, assembly, arm, fpu

I'm trying to create an ARM benchmark that  loop  over  the following instructions (in assembly), alone and in combination:

- Integer additions
- Integer multiplications
- Float point additions
- Float point multiplications

This is my code for integer operations:

```
int additions_int(int n) {

    int i, dummyValue = n;

    __asm (
        "MOV R0, #2\n"
        "MOV R1, #6\n"
    );

    for (i = 0; i < n/LOOP_STEP; i++) {

        __asm (
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
            "ADD R0, R0, R1\n"
        );
    }

    return dummyValue;
}


int multiplications_int(int n) {

    int i, dummyValue=n;

    __asm (
        "MOV R0, #2\n"
        "MOV R1, #6\n"
    );

    for (i = 0; i < n/LOOP_STEP; i++) {

        __asm (

            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"
            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"
            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"
            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"
            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"
            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"
            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"
            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"
            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"
            "MUL R0, R0, R1\n"

        );

    }

    return dummyValue;
}
```

The problem is in the float point operations. I checked [this documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.uan0015b/Cortex_A57_Software_Optimization_Guide_external.pdf), and I've tryed to do something like this:

```
float multiplications_fp(int n) {
    int i;
    float fn=n, dummyValue = fn;

    for (i = 0; i < n/LOOP_STEP; i++) {
        __asm (
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VMUL.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
        );
    }

    return dummyValue;
}


float additions_fp(int n) {
    int i;
    float fn=n, dummyValue = fn;

    for (i = 0; i < n/LOOP_STEP; i++) {
        __asm (
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n" 
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n" 
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n" 
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n" 
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n" 
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n" 
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n" 
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n" 
            "VADD.F32 R0, R0, R1\n"  
        );
    }

    return dummyValue;
}
```

Compiling with:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -march=armv7-a microbenchmark_arm.c -o microbenchmark_arm
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `vmul.f32 R0,R0,R1'
Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `vadd.f32 R0,R0,R1'
```

Can anyone say me what I'm doing wrong?

Can anyone show me an example of float point additions or multiplications for ARM Cortex-A architecture?

Comment: How about first reading the reference manual of the ARMv7A architecture and the datasheet of your target CPU plus the gcc manual? FYI: The loops are problematic, as not deterministic. Please first read how to properly benchmark.

Comment: I see an example spelled differently [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABDEAGJ.html): `VMUL.F32 d0,d0,d0`. I don't have experience with ARM FP, so cannot tell you how exactly to fix your syntax.

Comment: BTW regarding "example of float point additions or multiplications" you can see an example by disassembling compiled code.

Comment: did you try -mhard-float on your gcc command line?

Comment: for example for the raspberry pi I used:  -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mhard-float

Comment: You can use my gcc_perf project as a starting point. I wrote it to benchmark C vs intrinsic vs ASM code on different ARM platforms. https://github.com/bitbank2/gcc_perf/

Comment: For this code to be safe, you need to use constraints to tell gcc which registers your asm modifies.  Your integer loops change the value in `r0` without telling the compiler, which can easily lead to a crash or looping the wrong number of times.  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for links to docs.  BTW, I'd suggest looking at compiler output as a starting point for the instruction syntax.  (http://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Floating point instructions have a different register bank. For most of the instructions, you cannot share these registers. But this is the same register as for Neon SIMD instructions.

If you want single-precision, you can use:

```
VMUL.F32 s0, s0, s1
```

If you want double precision, you can use:

```
VMUL.F64 d0, d0, d1
```

Note that the floating-point engine may need to be enabled first if this is not done by the OS.

Comment: Here is a minimal runnable example that might help some people get starated: https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/ba19d7bf31dc35db2c6839766a94d3cdbe83847d/v7/vfp.S